# Support for embedded PNGs in .ico files as a favicon in browsers

Tags: optimization, minify, favicon, ico

I'm currently trying to optimize the file sizes of the resources of a website. Favicons are usually relatively big for their small image data.

While researching them I stumbled upon the fact that
Windows supports embedding PNGs in .ico files beginning with Windows Vista. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#PNG_format

This would allow to drastically reduce the size of the favicon while still using the .ico format.

Which browsers and browser versions support this type of .ico format?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use plain png files as your favicon. How about this?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

Check browser compatibilities though. You will most likely still have to provide old ico files for backwards compatibility. The wiki page contains a chart showing what is supported since when.

Comment: And are you sure your 16x16 or 32x32 traditional ico files realy are the best choice to safe on storage space? Those should be realy small already!